# How Can I Use onClick To Invoke ColdFusion Background Email Message

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am attempting to have an email alert (via  sent to me in the background whenever a 
user downloads a document from my webpage.  I have tried the following using an onClick event 
handler.  The code doesn't barf at all, and the document downloads fine, but the email message 
doesn't get fired.  It should be a relatively simple thing to do, but I am still pretty much a novice at this and may be missing something really obvious.  I would really appreciate any help.  Thanks!

This is the code I am trying to use to call the template as the user clicks to download the document:

```
<a href="doc_directory/doc_file.pdf" 
   onClick="doc_download_alert.cfm";>Click here to download document</a>
```

This is the code for the called template that is supposed to fire off the  message in the background:

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//dtd html 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="no">
    <cfmail
        type="html"
        from="my website"                       
        to="my_email_address@email.com"
        subject="download alert">
    <p>ALERT: document downloaded from my page
    </cfmail>
</cfprocessingdirective>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use `onClick` in that way. It is used to execute JavaScript code; not server-side code. However, you can use JavaScript code to make a call to your server.

Comment: How might I do that?  I am very much a novice with JS.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Do yourself a favor and learn jQuery (or similar JavaScript library). To get you started making an HTTP request from JavaScript see [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)